# add sub subpage endpoint to woocommerce plugin my-account section

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add a sub endpoint to custom endpoint defined for my woocommerce myaccount template. For example :

> custom endpoint - my-account/alumni
>   subendpoint - my-account/alumni/index

I have added the functionality to add the custom endpoint but when i am trying to add the sub-endpoint it is redirecting me to my-account/ and not loading the template

I have already tried refreshing the permalinks. and changing the position of endpoint and sub-endpoint definitions. I have written this code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_alumni_index_account_endpoint' );
function add_alumni_index_account_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'alumni-portal/alumni-index', EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_alumni-index_endpoint', 'alumni_index_account_endpoint_content' );
function alumni_index_account_endpoint_content() {
    //if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/alumni-index.php' );
    //}
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_alumni_portal_account_endpoint' );
function add_alumni_portal_account_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'alumni-portal', EP_PAGES );
}

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_account_menu_items', 10 );
function custom_account_menu_items( $menu_links ){
    //if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0,3 , true )
        + array( 'alumni-portal' => __('Alumni Portal') )
        + array_slice( $menu_links, 3, NULL, true );
    //}
    return $menu_links;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_alumni-portal_endpoint', 'alumni_portal_account_endpoint_content' );
function alumni_portal_account_endpoint_content() {
    //if ( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/alumni-portal.php' );
    //}
}

add_filter("woocommerce_get_query_vars", function ($vars) {
    foreach (["alumni-portal/alumni-index","alumni-portal"] as $e) {
        $vars[$e] = $e;
    }
    return $vars;
});
```

Result should be that my sub-endpoint should load its respective template rather than redirecting to my-account.

alumni-index.php has a simple code of hello

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit;
    }
?>
<p>hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `alumni-portal/alumni-index` as a separate endpoint, because this clashes with the `alumni-portal` endpoint. This is because rewrite endpoints will capture anything after `/` as their value. So `alumni-portal/alumni-index` is the same as `alumni-portal`, but the `alumni-portal` query var is set to `alumni-index`.

So rather than registering both endpoints, register `alumni-portal` a single endpoint, and then check for which value for `alumni-portal` is passed. If the value is `index`, then display the appropriate template.

So register your endpoint with the `woocommerce_get_query_vars` filter:

```
add_filter( 
    'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 
    function( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars['alumni'] = 'alumni';

        return $query_vars;
    }
);
```

Then use the `woocommerce_account_alumni_endpoint` action to display the page. These account endpoint hooks will pass the "value" of the endpoint as an argument to the callback function. So if I visit `my-account/alumni/index` the value passed will be `index`, and you can use this to display the appropriate template:

```
add_action( 
    'woocommerce_account_alumni_endpoint',
    function( $value ) {
        if ( $value === 'index' ) {
            wc_get_template( 'myaccount/alumni-index.php' );
        } else {
            wc_get_template( 'myaccount/alumni-portal.php' );
        }
    }
);
```

If you're filtering the account page title you don't get the value passed, but since you do get the endpoint you can get this with `get_query_var()`:

```
add_filter( 
    'woocommerce_endpoint_alumni_title',
    function( $title, $endpoint ){
        $value = get_query_var( $endpoint );

        if ( $value === 'index' ) {
            $title = 'Alumni Index';
        } else {
            $title = 'Alumni Portal';
        }

        return $title;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It worked! @jacob